# Save/Persist FIX::SessionSettings to file

Tags: c++, c++11, quickfix

In QuickFIX/j it is possible to save (an updated) SessionSettings to a file using [toStream](http://www.quickfixj.org/quickfixj/javadoc/1.4.0/quickfix/SessionSettings.html#toStream(java.io.OutputStream)):

```
public static void writeSettings(SessionSettings settings, File settingsFile) throws IOException {
    FileOutputStream settingsOut = new FileOutputStream(settingsFile);
    try {
        settings.toStream(settingsOut);
    } finally {
        settingsOut.close();
    }
}
```

However FIX::SessionSettings (c++) does not have this function defined in their [class reference](http://www.quickfixengine.org/quickfix/doc/html/class_f_i_x_1_1_session_settings.html).

Is there an easy way to achieve this using the C++ library, or should I port this method myself?

Comment: Isn't `std::ostream &  operator<< (std::ostream &, const SessionSettings &)` the one you are after?

Comment: @billz Yes! Completely missed it